# Add X amount of rows autofill data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to adds rows of data by autofilling from previously available data.

For example:

In column A, starting from A1, there is a title 'Charge 1', and then in A2, 'Discharge 1', and in A3, 'Charge 2', etc.

I would like to add a predefined number of cycles (one 'Charge' and one 'Discharge' + 1 more 'Charge') to column A that follows this series.

So if data in column A ends at Discharge 5, then add 5 cycles to fill this data down until Charge 11.

Comment: Take your problem in steps. Do you know how to add rows via VBA? Do you know how to use the autofill command via VBA? [MSDN - Filldown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarification

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Cycles()
    Dim cycleStrng1 As String, cycleStrng2 As String
    Dim lastCycle As Long, rowOffset As Long

    With Worksheets("Cycles").Range("A1") ' <--| change "Cycles" to your actual worksheet name
        cycleStrng1 = GetStringAtLeft(.Value)
        cycleStrng2 = GetStringAtLeft(.Offset(1).Value)
        With .End(xlDown)
            lastCycle = GetNumberAtRight(.Value)
            If GetStringAtLeft(.Value) = cycleStrng2 Then rowOffset = 1
            .Offset(rowOffset).Resize(2 * lastCycle) = Application.Transpose(FillCycles(lastCycle, cycleStrng1, cycleStrng2))
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function GetNumberAtRight(strng As String) As Long
    GetNumberAtRight = CLng(Right(strng, Len(strng) - InStrRev(strng, " ")))
End Function

Function GetStringAtLeft(strng As String) As String
    GetStringAtLeft = Left(strng, InStrRev(strng, " "))
End Function

Function FillCycles(lastCycle As Long, cycleStrng1 As String, cycleStrng2 As String) As Variant
    Dim iCycle As Long
    Dim strng As String

    For iCycle = lastCycle To 2 * lastCycle
        strng = strng & cycleStrng1 & iCycle & "|"
        strng = strng & cycleStrng2 & iCycle & "|"
    Next iCycle
    FillCycles = Split(Left(strng, Len(strng) - 1), "|")
End Function
```

Comment: I've tried your code, and there's a compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch


`With .End(xlDown)
            lastCycle = GetNumberAtRight(.Value)
            .Offset(1).Resize(2*lastCycle) = Application.Transpose(FillCycles(lastCycle, cycleStrng1, cycleStrng2))
        End With`

The error is within `Application.Transpose` for `.cycleStrng1`

Comment: Thanks for your work on this code - this is exactly what I'm looking for. Just a few errors: If the last cell in column A is, say, Charge 5, the macro will fill in 'Charge 5' in the next cell again, before filling in 'Discharge 5'. Similarly, if the last cell was 'Discharge 7', the macro would fill in 'Charge 7' rather than follow on and fill in 'Charge 8'

Could you also highlight the line of code which I can change if I needed it to fill in more lines - so that I can create a button which fills in 10 cycles or 50 cycles as needed.

Again, thanks for your work! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: from your question I got previous cycles would always end with a "Discharge". see edited code. you can easily adapt it for different needs

Comment: Even if the previous cycle ends at 'Discharge', the macro inserts 'Cycle', but still in the same number, rather than the next. So if the last cell is `Discharge 5` then running the script repeats the 5th cycle, which gives `Discharge 5 Charge 5 Discharge 5 Charge 6 Discharge 6 etc` instead of just starting from the 6th cycle

Comment: Try stepping through the code (click in any statement inside `Cycles` and keep pressing F8 to follow each statement being executed) and figure out needed changes (maybe an update of `lastCycle` along with the already `rowOffset` setting already there? :-)). Trial and error is the best way of learning.